# Why am I not able to get a distribution through Pandas .count()?

Tags: python, pandas

I"m not sure why the simple .count() is not working as expected for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
cols = ['die_sum']
df = []

for a in range(100000):
    die_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_sum = die_1 + die_2
    df.append(die_sum)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)
df['die_sum'] = df.die_sum.astype(str)
df.groupby('die_sum').count()
```

output:

[image: output:]

Answer (score 0):

You are running the `count()` method on an empty dataframe. Specify the column in the grouped dataframe on which you want to apply the `count()` method.

Changing the last line to the following should solve your issue

```py
>>> df.groupby('die_sum')['die_sum'].count()

die_sum
10     8552
11     5568
12     2780
2      2757
3      5612
4      8444
5     10982
6     13985
7     16570
8     13887
9     10863
Name: die_sum, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
result = df.groupby('die_sum')['die_sum'].count()
```

Or use `.size()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)
result = df.groupby('die_sum').size()


    die_sum
10     8413
11     5672
12     2830
2      2702
3      5640
4      8336
5     11133
6     13943
7     16684
8     13784
9     10863
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts) is also an option:

```
import random

import pandas as pd

cols = ['die_sum']
df = []
random.seed(3)  # Set seed for reproducibility
for a in range(100000):
    die_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_sum = die_1 + die_2
    df.append(die_sum)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)

counts = df['die_sum'].value_counts()

print(counts)
```

`counts`:

```
7     16503
6     13809
8     13733
5     11176
9     11118
4      8485
10     8351
11     5631
3      5584
12     2813
2      2797
Name: die_sum, dtype: int64
```